Why does :bd closes tabs instead of buffers?
I am using Neovide and I just don't understand. Maybe I am missing something about buffers? I just want to get rid of annoying empty buffers or old buffers that I don't use anymore. Only in the current tab of course. How can I achieve that and why?


Why does :bd closes tabs instead of buffers?

If the "deleted" buffer is displayed in a window and its alternate file doesn't have unsaved changes, then the window is closed.
If that window is the only one in a tab page, then the tab page is closed too.

Maybe I am missing something about buffers?

Most likely.

I just want to get rid of annoying empty buffers or old buffers that I don't use anymore.

Vim works just as well with 300 buffers as it does with 3 and having lots of buffers doesn't impact navigation negatively at all, so you don't have to micro-manage them.

Only in the current tab of course.

Buffers are global. They can't be tied to a specific window or tab page, so you can't "delete" a buffer in the current tab page.

how to cleanup the :bp, :bn list then? Those get worthless then.

Also what's the difference between :q and :bd then

@samuelnihoul perhaps read https://stackoverflow.com/q/26708822/4400820,  http://vimcasts.org/categories/managing-your-workspace/, https://codeinthehole.com/tips/vim-lists/, etc. The short answer, :bnext and :bprevious are probably the wrong tool for jumping where you want to be.

@samuelnihoul "How to cleanup the :bp, :bn list?" You don't. You leave the list as-is and you use a navigation method that is more suited to your actual needs.

@samuelnihoul "What's the difference between :q and :bd?" The former is a window command while the later is a buffer command. They have different usages. See :help :q and :help :bd.
